TextArea of richtext editor to pass backend same
if we enter some words in text area with the help of rich text editor as bold , italic and alignment ways, how do i send that data as the same format to the payload so that i could display the reponse in some other page in same way
As a fresher im unable to resolve it

First you need to understand the basics of how the text styling is rendered. In case of rich text editor, the underlying styling information are stored in markup format (e.g. Markdown is one of them).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
